# Why do i need to define a endpoint on a socket twice to start receiving data?

Tags: c#, sockets, snmp

I am doing a project were i want to receive SNMP traps from a device (just if you wanted to know). I used the code from this example http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/?page_id=117 and i am trying to just set up a barebones function from this. But what i dont understand is here:

```
public bool InitializeReceiver()
{
        _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        EndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
        _socket.Bind(localEP);

    if (!RegisterReceiveOperation())
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

At this line i set the IpAddress of the device and the port i want to listen too right?

```
EndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
```

And then here

```
public bool RegisterReceiveOperation()
{
    _peerIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)_peerIP;
    _inbuffer = new byte[64 * 1024];
    _socket.BeginReceiveFrom(_inbuffer, 0, 64 * 1024,
        SocketFlags.None, ref ep, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), _socket);
    return true;
}
```

What is the _peerIP? Do i set it to the same IPAddress and port as before? Or do i leave it like that?

Also as a note the original code from the site works and i receive the traps correctly but in my application i want the connection to be more managed and i cant really test it all the time. So if someone could clear up what those difrent IPEndPoint's are would be great.

Note 2: I removed a lot of try and catch blocks from my modified code that i posted here and other stuff that i dont think have anything to do with this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Socket communications always involves two endpoints: a local endpoint (the one you listen on), and a remote endpoint (the one you receive from or connect to). With connectionless oriented protocols like UDP, there is no need to bind to a local endpoint. However, if you do not explicitly bind to a specific local endpoint, the provider will automatically choose any that is available. Well, actually the same is true for connection oriented protocols as well when you use the local endpoint to connect to a remote host, instead of listening for incoming connections.

The endpoint in the `ReceiveFrom` family of methods is the endpoint you expect the data to come from. If you are willing to accept data from any endpoint, then you should specify `IPAddress.Any` and a port number of zero. If you supply a more specific endpoint, then any data from other sources is silently discarded, and only data from the specified endpoint is received. Note that the parameter is passed by reference. Upon method return, the variable will contain the actual endpoint from which data was received.

So, summing up: you need to define an endpoint twice because you are specifying both the local, and the remote endpoints. Plus, you can very well specify the remote device's IP address and port number in the `BeginReceiveFrom` method if you know this information beforehand and expect it to never change (kind of unlikely).

Comment: Should explicitly mention that if there are multiple network adapters on the machine, choosing a proper local endpoint is a must to send/receive packets at a specific adapter. That's the most common case to specify a local endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from the [Socket.Bind(..) MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind(v=vs.110).aspx)

@Remarks secion:

> Before calling Bind, you must first create the **local IPEndPoint** from which **you** intend **to communicate data.**

Now, this part is taken from the [Socket.BeginReceiveFrom(..) MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceivefrom(v=vs.110).aspx)

@Parameter 'remoteEP':

> An EndPoint that **represents the source of the data.**

And from Remarks:

> Before calling BeginReceiveFrom, you must explicitly bind the Socket to a local endpoint using the Bind method, or BeginReceiveFrom will throw a SocketException.

Comment: M8 i read that myself but i dont understand what the second endpoint is inside the BeginReceiveFrom since i already set my socket to the ip and port i want to listen too. Does it get set itself after it receives the data so i can leave it blank?

Comment: The one in the `Bind` method is the port YOU want to communicate to and the one inside the `BeginReceiveFrom` method is the IP where the data comes from. Its a bit confusing inside your code as your connection is on a local network. If you read the parts I made bold I'm sure you'll get it.

Comment: But what confuses me is that i set the IP address in the BIND where i want to communicate too. So if this wasnt on a local network(which it wont be later) in the bind i set both the IPAddress and the PORT and i dont need to set anything in the BeginReceiveFrom EndPoint (or essentialy IPAddress.Any and 0 as port)?

Comment: If you later on want it to communicate with an remote IP (a computer on another network) you only have to change the EndPoint inside the `BeginReceiveFrom` method.

Comment: So it wont matter if i will know that the device will stay on the same IP and the same PORT all the time?

Comment: That depends on your network configuration. Although I think when you use `IPAddress.Any` it will automatically get a the right IP, but that should be used when your local IP is dynamic. The first thing I always do is assign the computer to a static IP to prevent issues like that.